# react-image-annotate - How to save an image along with the annotations?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-redux

The npm package [react-image-annotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-annotate) gives a decent react component to annotate images.

This component uses a tag called `<ReactImageAnnotate />` for the annotate window. It has a prop called **onExit** which will give the details of all the data of that image we are working on.

My question is:
Suppose I did mark some things using a box in the image, and now I want to save/export/download that image along with that box. How can we do that?

Comment: How did you eventually solve this issue?