# how to save image annotations in real image annotate library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, annotations

The npm package react-image-annotate gives a decent react component to annotate images.

This component uses a tag called <ReactImageAnnotate /> for the annotate window. It has a prop called onExit which will give the details of all the data of that image we are working on.

My question is: Suppose I did mark some things using a box in the image, and now I want to save/export/download that image along with that box. How can we do that?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ReactImageAnnotate from "react-image-annotate"

function FileInput() {
const \[selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles\] = useState(\[\]);
const \[annotatedImageSrcs, setAnnotatedImageSrcs\] = useState(\[\]);

const handleFileChange = (event) =\> {
const files = event.target.files;
setSelectedFiles(\[...selectedFiles, ...files\]);
};

const processImages = async () =\> {
try {
const annotations = \[\];

      for (const file of selectedFiles) {
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = async () => {
          const imageBase64 = fileReader.result.split(',')[1];
          const imageBytes = new Uint8Array(atob(imageBase64).split('').map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)));
    
          const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/process_image', imageBytes, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            },
          });
    
          console.log(`Image ${file.name} processed successfully.`);
          console.log(response.data);
    
          annotations.push({
            name: file.name,
            annotatedImageSrc: response.data.annotated_image_src
          });
    
          if (annotations.length === selectedFiles.length) {
            setAnnotatedImageSrcs(annotations);
          }
        };
    
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error processing images:', error);
    }

};

return (
\<div\>
\<input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} multiple /\>
\<button onClick={processImages}\>Process Images\</button\>

      {annotatedImageSrcs.map(({ name, annotatedImageSrc }, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <h2>{`Annotated Image - ${name}`}</h2>
          <img src={`http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_annotated_image/${annotatedImageSrc}`} alt={`Annotated ${name}`} style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }} />
        </div>
      ))}
    
      {selectedFiles.map((file, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <h2>{`Selected Image - ${file.name}`}</h2>
          <img src={URL.createObjectURL(file)} alt={`Selected ${file.name}`} style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }} />
          <ReactImageAnnotate
            labelImages
            regionClsList={["Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie", "Delta"]}
            regionTagList={["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]}
            images={[
              {
                src: URL.createObjectURL(file),
                name: file.name,
                regions: []
              }
            ]}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>

);
}

export default FileInput;
```

this is a duplicate question of [duplicate :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70447179/react-image-annotate-how-to-save-an-image-along-with-the-annotations) but since this was unanswered , I am reposting it again .